# Get data from Facebook Graph API with JSON

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, json

I want to print the ID of the comment (eg. `10151828637085391_33268745`) from [this page](https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://gallery.erik-edgren.nu/photo/P1220672) but I don't know how to get pass the URL. After I had decoded the data with JSON and printed it out with `var_dump()` it looks like this:

```
array
  'http://gallery.erik-edgren.nu/photo/P1220672' => 
    array
      'comments' => 
        array
          'data' => 
            array
              ...
          'paging' => 
            array
              ...
```

So far so good. I have tried to write `$array->http://gallery.erik-edgren.nu/photo/P1220672->comments->data->id` but the `//` make the whole string to a comment on the website. I have even tried to add `\` before I print the `/` (`$array->http:\/\/galle...`) but I'm getting the following error message:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in ...`

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'd need to do `$array['http://gallery.erik-edgren.nu/photo/P1220672']['comments']['data']['id']`, since it's an array and not an object.

Comment: Ah! I didn't think about that :) Many thanks for your answer! I'll mark it when I can.